# Maximum length of SSDEEP hash algorithm's result

Tags: hash, hashcode

I can't find any information about the maximum length of a hash value calculated with the [ssdeep hash algorithm](https://ssdeep-project.github.io).

I want to store a ssdeep hash value inside a database by its hex digest represantation, but therefore I need to specify the length of the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I took a look at the [`fuzzy.h`](https://ssdeep-project.github.io/ssdeep/doc/api/html/fuzzy_8h_source.html) and its [documentation](https://ssdeep-project.github.io/ssdeep/doc/api/html/fuzzy_8h.html#a2309f23e98c4c0370f32e3e3cb09afa5) where I found the answer.

The macro is called `FUZZY_MAX_RESULT`. It defines a maximum length for the hash value of `148` ASCII characters / bytes:

```
#define SPAMSUM_LENGTH 64
#define FUZZY_MAX_RESULT (2 * SPAMSUM_LENGTH + 20)
```

> The longest possible length for a fuzzy hash signature (without the filename)